# Merge tag [facebook-fbml] and [fbml]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I request to please merge both the tags as both of them represent the same meaning and that is facebook markup language.

The tag [fbml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbml) do it  all so there should be no need to special specify a tag with name [facebook-fbml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-fbml)